# Pourquoi 'polynôme' et 'polynomial', 'binôme' et 'binomial' ?

Tags: écriture

Pourquoi la différence en écriture ?

> Polyn**ô**me et polyn**o**mial

> Binôme, binomial

(À savoir, ô contre o.)

Comment: Tout comme binôme, binomial pour rester dans les maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Polynôme** s'écrit avec un accent circonflexe pour compenser l'erreur inverse qui consiste à écrire **polygone** sans accent circonflexe ;-)

L'étymologie hybride du premier, mais latine quant à son suffixe **-nome**, aurait dû entraîner **polynome** alors que l'étymologie pleinement grecque du deuxième aurait dû entraîner l'orthographe **polygône**. Ce n'a pas été le choix des lexicographes...

Polynomial respecte lui son étymologie.

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-n%C3%B4me) confirme bien que l'accent circonflexe n'est pas étymologique, et que c'est par analogie avec des mots savants qui en ont un de "légitime", comme **symptôme**, que les mots en "-nôme" ont été prononcés de la même manière et portent donc cet accent.

On peut donc dire que la prononciation erronée en /ome/ s'est imposée (pour ceux qui font la différence) et qu'elle a entraîné la présence de ce circonflexe, et vice versa.

Certains se sont émus de cette anomalie, mais l'usage a prévalu.

> [Source 1](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=IAcAAAAAMAAJ&pg=GBS.PA2&hl=fr) O. Terquem et C. Gérono, Nouvelles annales de mathématiques, Tome 3, 1844, p 140
>
> *(1) L'Académie écrit polynôme avec l'accent circonflexe , et polygone sans accent. L'étymologie prescrit le contraire.*

> [Source 2](http://books.cedram.org/MALSM/SMA_1937-1938__5__K_0.pdf) *LE SÉMINAIRE DE MATHÉMATIQUES, 1933–1939* (Annotation de [Michèle Audin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mich%C3%A8le_Audin)) :
>
> *3. Sauf erreur ou omission, il s’agit du premier polynôme avec accent dans le séminaire. Nous avons vu polynome employé par Delsarte (archives Bourbaki, exposés 2-D et 2-I), Dieudonné (1-D), Élie Cartan (1-F), Henri Cartan (4-B), Weil (1-H, 1-I, 2-J), Dubreil-Jacotin (4-I), Dubreil (5-H), Chevalley (4-K, 5CD), et Pisot lui-même (5-E).
> Deux mots sur ce point minime d’orthographe : « nome » vient du latin nomen (nom,terme) par le mot binome. Il n’y a aucune raison grammaticale ou étymologique de le munir d’un accent circonflexe. Il en est pourtant affublé depuis 1798, pour des raisons de prononciation (« marquer la longueur de la voyelle et la protéger contre l’ouverture ») par analogie avec d’autres mots savants, d’origine grecque, comme symptôme. On trouve polynôme, avec
> accent, dans la littérature mathématique, y compris manuscrite, bien avant le séminaire Julia (par exemple, dans les lettres de Fatou citées dans [Aud09])... mais, par exemple, André Weil a écrit très systématiquement polynome (1) ... et a même réussi à le faire passer dans certains de ses articles imprimés (mais pas dans tous).
> Cette note a été rédigée grâce à l’aide de [Bernard Cerquiglini](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cerquiglini) (auteur de [Cer95]) et des articles « nôme » ; « binome » et « polynôme » du Trésor de la Langue française.*

Comment: Thanks @jlliagre. That looks a reasonable explanation. I cannot understand the negative vote.

Comment: Lack of sense of humour ;-) No worries.

Comment: +1 Donc, ça a rien à faire avec la prononciation (o ouvert) ? Et le principe s'applique également au "couple" binôme et binomial ?

Comment: Si, le TLFi justifie l'accent par la prononciation.  *L'accent circonflexe marque la longueur de la voyelle et la protège contre l'ouverture.* Je ne fais moi-même jamais la différence.

Answer (score 4):

La différence est due à la prononciation. L'étymologie veut qu'on le prononce avec un "o" fermé, et généralement, sur la dernière syllabe du mot, on met un accent circonflexe pour indiquer cette prononciation (*dôme*, *Rhône*, *geôle*, ...). Sinon, on le prononce plutôt<sup>(1)</sup> avec un "o" ouvert (*tome*, *trombone*, *fiole*, ...).

Cependant, ça ne concerne que la dernière syllabe. Quand le "o" est au milieu du mot comme dans "polynomial" ou "binomial", le "o" est quasiment toujours fermé. On n'a donc pas besoin d'un accent circonflexe.

---

(1) C'est assez variable. Quand il y a une consonne seule non accentuée, les deux sont possibles, selon les mots et parfois selon les accents régionaux. Sur certains mots on peut même entendre les deux prononciations. Voici la règle :

- Quand on a un accent circonflexe, on a forcément un "o" fermé : *symptôme*, *tôle*, *rôle*, ...
- Quand on a une voyelle double, on a quasiment toujours un "o" ouvert : *consonne*, *molle*, *homme*, *développe*, *botte*, ...
- Quand on a une voyelle simple et pas d'accent sur le "o", selon les consonnes les deux peuvent être possibles. *tome*/*atome*, *carbone*/*zone*,  ... Pour certaines consonnes on n'a que le "o" ouvert, comme avec les mots en "*-ore*" ou en "*-ope*".

Comment: Pas trop d'accord pour dire *Quand le "o" est au milieu du mot comme dans "polynomial" ou "binomial", le "o" est quasiment toujours fermé*. Contre exemple : économie, économe prononcés ouverts pour moi.